# How to get client IP in WCF service in Linux?

Tags: c#, wcf, mono

I have a WCF service that is working under Mono in Debian.
My goal is to obtain client IP address in service.
I've read a big amount of similar topics which show that the main solution is to use `RemoteEndpointMessageProperty`:

```
OperationContext oOperationContext = OperationContext.Current;
MessageProperties oMessageProperties = oOperationContext.IncomingMessageProperties;

var prop = oMessageProperties[RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name];
RemoteEndpointMessageProperty oRemoteEndpointMessageProperty = prop as RemoteEndpointMessageProperty;

string szAddress = oRemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Address;
int nPort = oRemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Port;
```

I did the same as shown above.
But the problem is that `oMessageProperties` doesn't contain key `RemoteEndpointMessageProperty.Name`, it has only "Encoder" with value `System.ServiceModel.Channels.BinaryMessageEncoder`.

Anyone knows why this happens and how to fix this?

I am using NetTcpBinding under Mono 3.2.8

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
var iPAddress = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` is `null` in my service. I added `ASP.NET Compatibility Mode` but it didn't help either